# What does SOS in SQL Server stand for?

Tags: sql-server

I am reading [SQL Server 2012 Internals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735658560) book now. There are several phrases with SOS acronym, such as "SOS Scheduler" (in chapter about the scheduler), "SOS Memory node" (in chapter about the free buffer list and the lazywriter). But I can't find the meaning anywhere.

Comment: "SQL Operating System"

Comment: Don't think so. Here's the sentence, "Each instance of SQL Server has one lazywriter thread for each SOS Memory node created in SQLOS, with every instance having at least one lazywriter thread."

Comment: I believe the two acronyms are still interchangeable. You could always ask Kalen, who wrote the book, she's [`@sqlqueen`](http://twitter.com/sqlqueen) on twitter.

Comment: the first thing that popped into my mind was this `In answer to the first question, SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD represents a SQLOS worker (thread) that has yielded the CPU, presumably to another worker. ` from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joesack/archive/2009/03/18/should-you-worry-about-sos-scheduler-yield.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually usually referred to as `SQLOS` and it means SQL Server Operating System.

- [Details in this series](https://mssqlwiki.com/2013/01/10/sql-server-operating-system-sos-series-1/)

Also it can be found referenced in documentation in some places, e.g. [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176083(v=sql.110).aspx):

> [...] associated with the SQL Server Operating System (SQLOS). The SQLOS is responsible for managing operating system resources that are specific to SQL Server.